# fetchmail delivering mail to local mailbox sometimes, should go to an exchange server

Tags: fetchmail

This feels like a sendmail problem, but I have a feeling that some part of fetchmail is duplicating some of sendmail's behavior, because when it happens, and I reboot fetchmail, it stops happening - until the next time.

I'm using fetchmail (6.3.17+GSS+RPA+NTLM+SDPS+SSL+HESIOD+NLS+KRB5) on CentOS 6.8 to grab mail from a few mailboxes and send them to an internal Exchange server.  The fetchmail config file (with accounts and passwords removed is

```
set syslog
set postmaster "it@our.domain"
set showdots
set bouncemail
set properties ""
set invisible
set no softbounce

poll pop.host port 995 proto POP3 timeout 12
user "user1" there with password "..." is user2@our.domain here ssl sslproto TLS1
user "user2" there with password "..." is user2@our.domain here ssl sslproto TLS1
```

And our /etc/mail/mailertable says

```
our.domain smtp:[exchange.our.domain]
```

So fetchmail *usually* delivers the mail it fetches from pop.host to the exchange server.

But every once in a while fetchmail starts trying to deliver the mail to local mailboxes (which don't exist).  As I said at the top, restarting the fetchmail daemon fixes this, I'd expect restarting sendmail would be what was needed, but it isn't.

It logs lines like this in /var/log/maillog when that happens (I know this is out of sequence, but it looks like procmail logs its message, returns failure, and then fetchmail logs its message

```
Sep 11 03:50:39 mailer procmail[21164]: Unknown user "user1"
Sep 11 03:50:39 mailer fetchmail[1029]: reading message user1@smtp.host:
14 of 14 (348741 octets) (log message incomplete)
```

I'm really hoping that someone has seen this before, or if not, could tell me where the code is in the fetchmail source that hands mail it's fetched to sendmail so I could add some more log messages.

Comment: What is the `hostname` of the system that runs `fetchmail`?

Comment: the hostname is "mailer"

Comment: Hmm, maybe crank the logging level in fetchmail? (A sendmail host named after `our.domain` can be problematical, but if it's `mailer.our.domain` that should be okay.)